# Deriving the in-sample error for linear model from the elements of statistical learning

Tags: references

From the elements of statistical learning, it was claimed that 
$$
\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N ||h(x_i) ||^2 \sigma^2_\varepsilon= \frac{p}{N}\sigma^2_\varepsilon$$

where $h(x_i) = X(X^TX)^{-1}x_i$. Can someone show me how to prove this ? Thanks

This came from the image below

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
\sum_{i=1}^{N}\|\textbf{h}(x_i)\|^2
=\sum_{i=1}^{N}\|\textbf{X}(\textbf{X}^T\textbf{X})^{-1}x_i\|^2
=tr\{(\textbf{X}(\textbf{X}^T\textbf{X})^{-1}\textbf{X}^T)^T(\textbf{X}(\textbf{X}^T\textbf{X})^{-1}\textbf{X}^T)\}
=tr\{(\textbf{X}(\textbf{X}^T\textbf{X})^{-1}\textbf{X}^T)(\textbf{X}(\textbf{X}^T\textbf{X})^{-1}\textbf{X}^T)\}
=tr\{\textbf{X}(\textbf{X}^T\textbf{X})^{-1}(\textbf{X}^T\textbf{X})(\textbf{X}^T\textbf{X})^{-1}\textbf{X}^T\}
=tr\{\textbf{X}(\textbf{X}^T\textbf{X})^{-1}\textbf{X}^T\}
=tr\{\textbf{X}^T\textbf{X}(\textbf{X}^T\textbf{X})^{-1}\}
=tr\{\textbf{I}_p\}=p
$$
Q.E.D.